# "for" loop inside a Text::Template template

Tags: perl, templates, texttemplate

I'm trying to use perl [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Text-Template/) for short templates and so far failed to get it to iterate over an array.

Here is a short test program I wrote to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Text::Template;
my $template = Text::Template->new(TYPE => 'STRING', SOURCE => <<'__EOT__');
array[0]: { $array[0] }
{ foreach my $i (@array) { }
 {$i}
}
__EOT__
print $template->fill_in(HASH => { array => [qw(item1 item2)]});
```

According to the Text::Template manual I expected this to print:
    array[0]: item1
    item1
    item2
But instead it prints
    array[0]: item1

(i.e. the output of the first line outside the loop and an empty line).

I couldn't find anywhere on the web any example of someone actually using a loop inside a template, though the documentation says it should "just work".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
my $template = Text::Template->new(TYPE => 'STRING', SOURCE => <<'__EOT__',  DELIMITERS => [qw(<% %>)],);
```

Pick different delimiters. The documentation advises you to do so several times for various reasons, mostly for being easier to work with because Perl code also uses `{}` braces. It also says:

> Because the parsing of templates is simplified by the absence of backslash escapes, using alternative DELIMITERS may speed up the parsing process by 20-25%. This shows that my original choice of { and } was very bad.

Just `{$i}` does not work here because it is in void context. The documentation says:

> The result of the last statement executed will be evaluted in scalar context; the result of this statement is a string, which is interpolated into the template in place of the program fragment itself.

Rewrite it with the `$OUT` variable:

```
<% foreach my $i (@array) {
    $OUT .= $i
} %>
```

The documentation says:

> Anything you append to this variable will appear in the output of the template. Also, if you use $OUT in a program fragment, the normal behavior, of replacing the fragment with its return value, is disabled; instead the fragment is replaced with the value of $OUT.

```
<% $OUT .= $_ for @array %>
```

Same result, but shorter.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answers.

I'm already aware of $OUT and the option for different delimiters but the problem is that this isn't just a single "$i" that I want to repeat in the loop. I actually want to interpolate it inside about 5 lines of text and possibly more variables.
This part of the template should actually be:
    server {$server_ip} { 
      address = {$server_ip}
      active = 1
      weight = {$weight}
    }
(it's part of [lvs.cf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/lvs.cf)). Putting all these lines in one "$OUT .=" sort of defeats the purpose of a template.
(to be continued..)

Comment: (..continued).
When trying the different delimiters I got the following errors:
    array[0]: item1
    Program fragment delivered error ``Missing right curly or square bracket at template line 2, at end of line syntax error at template line 2, at EOF''
    Program fragment delivered error ``Unmatched right curly bracket at template line 4, at end of line syntax error at template line 4, near ";
#line 4 template }"''
So it looks like it won't allow me to break the "for" body to multiple fregmants as I expected from the manual.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of experiments indicate that this:

```
{ stuff }
```

Is turned into (effectively) something like this pseudo-perl:

```
my $x = eval(stuff);
$template =~ s/{ stuff }/$x/;
```

So the "stuff" needs to be an expression so that it returns something to put into the template. Your "stuff" is a `foreach` loop which doesn't have a value so your template doesn't do anything interesting.

If you look at the tests for `Text::Template` (always go to the test suite for examples, the test suites for CPAN packages are invaluable for learning how things work), you'll see things like this:

```
{ $t = ''; foreach $n (1 .. 20) { $t .= $n . ' ' } $t }
```

Note the way `$t` is being used. That indicates that you want something more like this for your template:

```
array[0]: { $array[0] }
{ $t = ''; foreach my $i (@array) { $t .= "\t$i\n" } }
```

There's also the [`$OUT`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Template/lib/Text/Template.pm#The_%24OUT_variable) special variable which can take the place of `$t` above. The documentation for CPAN packages is generally pretty good and well worth reading, you'll miss it when you work in other languages.